# First time working on 3D game: exporting steps after designer finishes 3D characters?

Tags: textures, ios, pipeline, export, cinema-4d

First time making a 3D game so could use advice. The designer is creating 3D characters with Cinema 4D (https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/).

What steps are required to go from his 3D models to generate the files and texture maps (e.g., diffuse, normal) required to render the characters on iOS?

Is this export done within Cinema 4D, or does there need to be an intermediary step?

Does the process change if the characters are animated?